# Ubuntu 16.04 internet not working but SSH works after upgrade

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, dns

I just upgraded from 14.04 to 16.04 but now the internet does not work.

I am able to SSH into the box.

I can ping 8.8.8.8

I have tried `sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf` and `sudo reboot` but that didn't resolve it.

I have also tried 

`sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf
sudo ln -s ../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
sudo resolvconf -u`

And still nothing

EDIT:

`ip addr show` outputs

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: em1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:26:6c:f7:b2:b8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 209.123.74.69/27 brd 209.123.74.95 scope global em1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::226:6cff:fef7:b2b8/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: em2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:26:6c:f7:b2:b9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

ifconfig outputs

```
em1       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:26:6c:f7:b2:b8  
          inet addr:209.123.74.69  Bcast:209.123.74.95  Mask:255.255.255.224
          inet6 addr: fe80::226:6cff:fef7:b2b8/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:12013 errors:0 dropped:10 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:7250 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2076402 (2.0 MB)  TX bytes:1061991 (1.0 MB)
          Memory:c0000000-c001ffff 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:13464 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:13464 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:1003144 (1.0 MB)  TX bytes:1003144 (1.0 MB)
```

and the `/etc/resolv.conf` is empty

Comment: What is the content of /etc/resolv.conf? What does "ip addr show" give? And just to be sure, you are not able to resolve domain names right? (e.g., ping google.com)

Comment: @EricMintz went ahead and updated answer with the outputs

Answer (score 0):

The empty /etc/resolv.conf file looks like issue - that's where you should see something like

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Add those into it and see if that resolves the internet connectivity issue. If it does, you can make the change permanent by changing it in the Network Manager settings.

Also you can add ones for IPv6:

```
nameserver 2001:4860:4860::8888
nameserver 2001:4860:4860::8844
```